# Filament sticks to nozzle

Tags: filament, heated-bed, bed-leveling, adhesion

Normally, I'm all fine with my printer and filament. But today I changed the filament for another brand and no matter what, it sticks to the nozzle so nothing comes to the bed and soon my nozzle is full of PLA... I use a sheet of paper for printer to level the bed at 0.1 mm. While leveling, I get the nozzle close enough to feel a bit of resistance from the paper while moving that sheet. Please help me...

Comment: What temperature are you running your nozzle/bed at?

Comment: Eric, were you able to resolve thanks to any answer below? Or would you like to share some other advice? This question reflects issue of many, it deserves to be resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is not so much that the filament is sticking to the nozzle; it's that the filament is not sticking to the bed.

You've confirmed that you have correct clearance for the nozzle to bed distance. The next considerations are bed temperature and nozzle temperature. New brands often require new parameters.

Consider to raise the bed temperature 5 °C. If you're not using any adhesive medium, perhaps a bit of glue stick will help to have the filament stick better/properly.

It's unlikely that the nozzle temperature is incorrect, as too low would result in a nozzle clog, while too high would "drizzle out" and be everywhere, but don't reject too-high entirely.

If you can get the bed adhesion correct, your nozzle should remain clear.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @fred_dot_u remarks:

### Decrease initial layer speed

Try to print the initial layer at lower (very low speed). Start from 20 mm/s, move down even to 5-10 mm/s (e.g. just decrease speed% from the menu). I had many such issues when printing in too high speed (even directly on kapton tape): filament could not stick to the bed so quickly and rolled just after the nozzle - and slowing down almost always helped.

You may also decrease height of first layer e.g. by 25-50 %, and try to increase "Initial Layer Line Width" (e.g. 120 % in Cura). Increase temperatures by 5-10 degrees also helps sometime.

If this will not improve, then try to enhance adhesion.